# Sending UDP Packet in C#

Tags: c#, networking, udp, send, packet

I have a game server (WoW).
I want my players to download my custom patches to the game.
I've done a program that checks for update/downloading things.
I want my program to send a packet to my game server if player have all my patches. I dont need any response from the server, it will handle it, but its another story.

**So I want to know, how to send a packet to a server.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,
ProtocolType.Udp);

IPAddress serverAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.255");

IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverAddr, 11000);

string text = "Hello";
byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text );

sock.SendTo(send_buffer , endPoint);
```

Comment: Great solution. You will need to add these C# "using"s:
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

Answer (score 18):

```
static void SendUdp(int srcPort, string dstIp, int dstPort, byte[] data)
{
    using (UdpClient c = new UdpClient(srcPort))
        c.Send(data, data.Length, dstIp, dstPort);
}
```

Usage:

```
SendUdp(11000, "192.168.2.255", 11000, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello!"));
```