# Send and receive UDP data

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending UDP Packet in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637697/sending-udp-packet-in-c-sharp)

I have some data in hex format that I would like to send to a UDP server and then get a response back from the server that contains some data. How would I go about doing this in C#?

I might add that I do not have local access to the server, I would just like to see which response I get by sending this particular data to it.

Comment: Look at [http://stackoverflow.com/a/2637791/884410](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2637791/884410)

Comment: I have tried using the UdpClient.Send method to send data to the UDP server, and that worked I am guessing, but I would like to be able to get a response from the server too.

Answer (score 0):

1- [A Chat Application Using Asynchronous UDP sockets](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16935/A-Chat-Application-Using-Asynchronous-UDP-sockets)
[image]

2- [Send UDP packet in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/72657/Send-UDP-packet-in-C)

3- [Testing TCP and UDP socket servers using C# and .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2614/Testing-TCP-and-UDP-socket-servers-using-C-and-NET)

4- [Receive and send data](http://www.nuclearprojects.com/xplane/receivedata.shtml)

5- [UDP Send and Receive using threads in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8877/UDP-Send-and-Receive-using-threads-in-VB-NET)

6- [A UDP based Reliable Data Transfer Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11046/A-UDP-based-Reliable-Data-Transfer-Library)

7- [msdn microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex%28vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I have tried your second link before, and while it would seem that it should do what I wanted, I am not getting any data back. Could that mean the server is not responding with anything?

Comment: share with us what you did, write some code so we can see what's wrong