# how to send dhcp discover packets using C#?

Tags: c#

I have been searching for quite a while and cannot seem to find a working DHCP Client implementation example in C#. I am brand spankin' new to Network Programming, but am doing some research that requires me to write a manual DHCP client and to implement Auto-IP if there is no DHCP server.
i want to send DHCP discover packets using C# to get anther IP address

Answer (score 1):

DHCP uses UDP as transport protocol, so you need to send UDP datagram with DHCP payload.

How to send UDP is already answered here: [Sending UDP Packet in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637697/sending-udp-packet-in-c-sharp)

DHCP frame fromat is described in many places on the internet e.g. http://www.tarunz.org/~vassilii/TAU/protocols/dhcp/frame.htm

Here is another example DHCP server: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20431/A-Small-DHCP-Server-Using-UDP-With-Asynchronous-Ca

Unfortunately it seems like there is not C# library for querying DHCP server, but you may use WinAPI via P/Invoke: [DHCP Client API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363345(v=vs.85).aspx)

EDIT: After bit of searching, here is C# wrapper for WinAPI calls: http://www.rupj.net/portfolio/dhcp-web-services.html
and http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dhcpsapi/DhcpGetClientInfo.html