# send Http Request to Udp service accepting service

Tags: c#, http, udp, blazor

I have old windows service which only accept the UDP messages. In my modern code send only http request. Is it possible to convert http request to udp request and response  with out using any external sources?

Comment: Blazor Wasm or Blazor Server?  With the server type you have a normal C# program, UDP should not be a problem. With Wasm you can forget it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "UDP request" but only a UDP datagram without any inner meaning by its own. The service uses some application protocol (the "inner meaning") implemented on top of UDP . As long as this protocol not known it is unclear how a "converted" request should even look like and thus no conversion is possible.

Answer (score 0):

As @Henk-Holterman points out, the type of Blazor implementation is important.

A Blazor WASM app can only do what a Browser+JS can do - UDP isn't supported. If you need to call an API via UDP, do it from a regular WebAPI method on your server which calls the UDP method using C# code.

If you're using Blazor server, just use a C# UDP method to make the request.

[Sending UDP Packet in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637697/sending-udp-packet-in-c-sharp)